# Zombie objects in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework

I create few entities in `Entity Framework`. They are automatically added.

**Question 1:** Is it normal that `MyEntity.CreateMyEntity` automatically adds entity to the context?

Now, I want to save them but if they violate the database constraints I get exception, nothing is persisted -- RIGHT, BUT -- these objects remain in the `ObjectContext` which I do not want.

I tried to run that code as:

```
using (var t = new TransactionScope()) {
   ...create entities...
   try
   {
     context.SaveChanges();
     t.Complete();
     context.AcceptAllChanges();
   }
   catch
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Ooops");
   }
}
```

but even if I ran it in the transaction, these entities remain in the context.

**Question 2:** What am I missing? Do I have to remove them manually?

Comment: Can you show the code where objects created with `MyEntity.CreateMyEntity` are automatically attached to the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option to avoid unwanted objects without having to dispose the context is to manually detach them after you have committed the changes to the DB using [`Detach()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738697.aspx):

> You can detach objects from an object
>   context when they are no longer
>   required. To do this, call the Detach
>   method. This reduces the amount of
>   memory used.

```
context.Detach(yourEntity);
```

Be careful with related entities though, if your entity has related objects the related entities will not be detached automatically.

Answer (score 0):

All changes remain in context until you delete those changes. Unsuccesful save wont cancel changes. What do you mean by CreateMyEntity? Changes are added to context when you use `AddObject` or when you reference them in Entities already added.

Answer (score 0):

If something goes wrong(exception) - you must dispose context (because it is already wrong) and start over: create new datacontext, fetch needed data, create new entities and etc...

P.S.: or you can fix problems and save context.